# Как разместить блок под блоком с абсолютным позиционированием

Tags: html, css

Есть блок c position:absolute, нужно под ним разместить блок так, чтобы он не наплывал на предыдущий (не всхлопывался). При этом он должен быть в рамках контейнера.
Для предыдущего блока поставлено position:absolute с целью сделать фон на всю ширину экрана, а не только в рамках контейнера.

Comment: Пример кода в студию. А то не очень понятно кто кого чем куда.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант поместить в отдельный блок

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.abs {
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.abs .b1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.abs .b2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="abs">
   <div class="b1"></div>
   <div class="b2"></div>
</div>
```